# I have an apache camel test case which is failing because of different object instances getting created. The object instances are having different IDs

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, apache-camel, springjunit4classrunner

Following is the error which I am getting -

```
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://send Body of message: 0. Expected: <notification.scheduler.model.email.EmailNotificationRequest@943700a4> but was: <notification.scheduler.model.email.EmailNotificationRequest@c730128e>
Expected :<notification.scheduler.model.email.EmailNotificationRequest@943700a4> 
Actual   :<notification.scheduler.model.email.EmailNotificationRequest@c730128e>
```

The configuration of my class is as follows -

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = CustomerNotificationSchedulerApplication.class)
public class PrepareEmailReminderBodyRouteTest {


    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:prepareEmailReminder")
    private ProducerTemplate producer;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:send")
    private MockEndpoint mockSendEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    private EmailNotificationRequestConfiguration emailNotificationRequestConfiguration;

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        camelContext.getRouteDefinition("prepareEmailReminderRoute").adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:sendEmail")
                        .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                        .to(mockSendEndpoint);
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is the failing test case that is failing at `mockSendEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(request);` -

```
@Test
@DirtiesContext
public void whenOneRevisionPropertyListIsRetrievedThenSendOneEmailWithEmailTemplate() throws Exception {
    Journal journal = new Journal();
    journal.setEmail("supportX@gmail.com");

    Author author = new Author();
    author.setEmail("mail@mail.to");

    SubmissionDAO sub = new SubmissionDAO();
    sub.setSubmissionId("111111111");
    sub.setRevision(1);
    sub.setJournal(journal);
    sub.setAuthors(Collections.singletonList(author));

    String email = sub.getJournal().getEmail();
    String[] fetchEmail = email.split(",");
    String fromEmail = fetchEmail[0];
    String bccEmail = emailNotificationRequestConfiguration.getBcc().get("default");
    List<String> bccEmails = StringUtils.isNotBlank(bccEmail) ? Arrays.asList(bccEmail.split(",")) : Collections.emptyList();
    
    EmailNotificationRequest request = new EmailNotificationRequest();
    request.setTo(Collections.singletonList("mail@mail.to"));
    request.setSubject("Incomplete submission to Biology, ID: 111111111");
    request.setFrom(fromEmail);
    request.setBcc(bccEmails);
    request.setBody(escapeHtml4(IOUtils.toString(getSystemResourceAsStream("revision-reminder.html"), UTF_8)));

    mockSendEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
    mockSendEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(request);

    producer.send(ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext)
            .withProperty(ExchangeProperties.FILTERED_SUBMISSIONS_LIST_PROPERTY, Collections.singletonList(sub))
            .build());

    mockSendEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

How do I assert those object instances? Is there any way? Or am I doing anything wrong here?

Also FYI,
I am setting the exchange body in the Processor with a new EmailNotificationRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that the error is kind of a bit misleading.

The test case was actually failing due to the request body which I was setting & asserting. The request body in my case is an HTML template. And I was trying to assert it with a wrong HTML template.

When I used the correct HTML template, the test case passed.

Answer (score 1):

The `AssertionError` complains that **the two object instances are not equal** what is obvious because **they are not the same instance**.

One of them is created in your application, the other is created in your test case.

If you want to be able to **directly compare them**, you have to [implement equals and hashcode methods](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts) of the type `EmailNotificationRequest`.

The other way is to **compare single object attribute values** instead of the whole instance (for example `subject`).

To do this, you can **get the received exchanges** from the [Camel Mock](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/mock-component.html) like this

```
List<Exchange> messages = mockSendEndpoint.getReceivedExchanges()
```

You can then take a single message from the list or iterate through all messages to compare subject, to, from etc. with the expected values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer burki. But I already have implemented equals & hashcode method in the ```EmailNotificationRequest``` class. The issue was something else.